# CSS Issue - Scroll on bottom box margin

Tags: css, scroll

Trying to apply margin-bottom to the box looking like this:

[image]

It seems like when you have overflow: auto or scroll; it just cuts off text like this, and applies margin on the bottom on the element. Any way I can make this margin before someone scrolls down?

Comment: If I understood it correctly you need a `padding` for the bottom part of your box?

Comment: Padding or margin... as long as the text is not cut off.

Comment: It sounds to me like you just need to make the `height` taller, though we would need to see your code to be sure.